# Smart coding and "abstract" thinking to simplify template variations

Tags: html, css

I have this base HTML/CSS template out  of which I will do a lot of child websites that will use different colours and image variations for stuff like `<h>` tags, background color, etc etc.

I am looking for approaches to modify the base theme and make it so that in order to create child templates with color variations I will modify a single line of code (something like `.this-smart-class{color: #mycolorcodehere)` and voila, all the elements using that color change.

I am already cooking a method to do this myself, but I am a beginner/intermediate in front end development and I would be curious of different approaches to do this. 
I am looking to use only CSS for this, maybe some jQuery but only if proves to make it a lot practical.

**To better understand the question have a look at the screenshot:
variations of the same layout.**

If you find this question to "unspecific" please ask me before voting down or closing it and I will break it in multiple questions, but I think good answers may come out of this, I might not use the proper terms to be as specific as I want as I am not experienced enough.

[image]

Comment: CSS itself does not give you lots of options to reuse code. Maybe you should consider using LESS / SCSS / SASS etc.

Comment: SASS is one of the options, you can use variables for color or font sizes, so if you want to make a new theme u just need to change the variable value. and if you are familiar with WordPress, you can use rtPanel theme and its Child theme which is in sass and responsive too.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be best to use a CSS preprocessor (I prefer [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)).
You can make different color configuration files like for example "color-config-red.less" and "color-config-violet.less" where you define your different colors in variables like `@background-color` etc. and reuse them over the whole project. With that set up you can simply include the different color configurations for different websites while having the same layout.

Comment: Uhum.. this seems to be way to do it. I'll start learning about LESS

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use a number of generic classes which I can apply to any number of elements.

For example:

```
.smalltext { font-size: 0.8em }
.bold { font-weight: bold }
.clear { clear: both }
.highlight { background-color: #999999 }
```

I have mentioned this before and some people were critical of it but it works for me.

Then I can say:

```
<div id="footer" class="smalltext"></div>
<div id="box-header" class="highlight bold"></div>
```

Comment: this is what I'm working on right now.. although an approach with LESS / SCSS / SASS seems quite interesting.. new stuff to learn